# How can I find a label that is in a webpart, but not in .js files?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, label, developer-tools, nintex-workflow

On a SharePoint webpage there is a webpart which contains the label `Leistungszeitraum`. The problem I have is that I don't find the label in any of the JavaScript classes I have nor do I find it in a list of my Website Contents.

[image]

I used the developer tools and it showed me this:

[image: Developer Tools]

Where can I find the label `Leistungszeitraum` so that I can change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("nf-label-control")[0]
```

Or jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var labelText = $(".nf-label-control").text() 
    </script>
```

Provide more details if need further help.

Comment: Can you tell me where I have to write this codepart and do you know where I can find the field in SharePoint Designer?